# EnableCors always return wildcard for allowed origins in Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have one scenario to send an ajax post request from http to https (have to do that for some complex reasons), and I need to pass credentials for the sake of cookies.

I use Web Api in server side, with NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors to enable Cors request.

The code in client side:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.sitename.com/api/xxx',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            '': 1
        },
        headers: {
            '__AntiXsrfTokenKey': 'whatevertokenhere'
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

Web Api settings:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

EnableCors attribute for controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.sitename.com", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
public class XXXController : ApiController
```

The preflight request header:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, __AntiXsrfTokenKey, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://www.sitename.com
```

The response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: __AntiXsrfTokenKey,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The problem is clearly that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is returning a wildcard *, instead of the request origin which I specified in the attribute of the controller 'http://www.sitename.com'. So I end up of the error:

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://www.sitename.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Does any one know why is that behavior and how I can set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin domain correctly in the EnableCors attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found this in web.config within system.webServer

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pattern="(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="*" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```